# Generating random numbers which allows some repetition within a given range

Tags: c, mpi

I'm writing an MPI program where I'm **allowing each process** to generate it's **own random number** within an elapsed time where i would **want some process to have identical random numbers** generated with some **other process.** For example, a simple printf statement:

```
Process 1 has generated the number 19
Process 2 has generated the number 8
Process 3 has generated the number 19
.
.
```

Therefore, process 1 and 3 generated the same random number. Also, to ensure that i can obtain identical random number generated, i will constraint to only integer values, not doubles or floats.

I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define numprocess 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank,size;
    int rand_value;
    int lower,upper;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

    upper = 20;
    lower = 0;
    rand_value = rand()%(upper-lower);
    printf("Process %d generated a random number of %d\n",rank,rand_value);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

but I'm getting the output of:

```
Process 0 generated a random number of 7
Process 2 generated a random number of 7
Process 8 generated a random number of 7
Process 1 generated a random number of 7
Process 3 generated a random number of 7
Process 4 generated a random number of 7
Process 5 generated a random number of 7
Process 6 generated a random number of 7
Process 7 generated a random number of 7
Process 9 generated a random number of 7
Process 11 generated a random number of 7
Process 10 generated a random number of 7
Process 16 generated a random number of 7
Process 17 generated a random number of 7
Process 19 generated a random number of 7
Process 13 generated a random number of 7
Process 12 generated a random number of 7
Process 18 generated a random number of 7
Process 15 generated a random number of 7
Process 14 generated a random number of 7
```

Comment: `rand()` produces a pseudo-random number. consider using `std::random_device` for truly random numbers.

Comment: What is `value` and where is it initialized?

Comment: I don't know what MPI means, but didn't you forget to call [srand()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_srand.htm) ?

Comment: If you're on Un*x try reading `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Use the MPI rank in order to seed the RNG. `rank%2` looks like a fit here.

Comment: Keep in mind third party libraries might invoke `rand()` so even if you seed two ranks with the same value, you might still end up with different suites of random numbers, so you’d rather use `rand_r()`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen apologies, its rand_value instead of value

Comment: @Broman it's supposed to be rand_value instead of value. It should compile then.

Comment: Quoting from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/rand): "srand() seeds the pseudo-random number generator used by rand(). **If rand() is used before any calls to srand(), rand() behaves as if it was seeded with srand(1).** Each time rand() is seeded with srand(), it must produce the same sequence of values. "

Comment: @RichardHodges `random_device` is better than `rand` but it is not guaranteed to be non-pseudo. Also, it's C++ and not C.

Comment: @Broman I see the c++ tag has been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do like this:

```
srand(time(NULL)+rank * 10000);
```

Using `time` will ensure that you get a different output on each run, and using `rank` makes sure (with high probability but not 100%) that each thread has a different seed. The constant 10000 is an arbitrary constant just to decrease the probability that two threads from accidentally gets the same seed.

But this is a far better method:

```
const int current_time = time(NULL);

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

srand(current_time+rank);
```

Or using `MPI_Bcast`

```
int current_time;

MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);

if(rank == 0)
    current_time = time(NULL);

MPI_Bcast(&current_time, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
srand(current_time+rank);
```

Comment: @Broman thanks but I'm confused. The second segment, using MPI_Bcast does not require srand(current_time + rank)?

Comment: @Broman  Also, if i were to set the lower and upper bound range for the random number, do i implement it by srand(current_time+rank) % (upper-lower), as the modulo of the difference seemed to work somehow?

Comment: @Broman indeed, the goal is to also ensure that there IS a probability that some processes will end up generating the same random number. To rephrase, on the first run, all 20 processes for example might have all different random number by chance. On the second run, there might be 3 or 4 processes sharing the same random number and so on.

Comment: @troopers97 Yes, you need srand. I have corrected the post.